# Left Alt button toggles between open windows and consumes <Alt> key combinations

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04.x to 18.04.3 on my Lenovo X1 notebook and at first <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> key was working as expected.

All of a sudden, I have this very strange issue: Pressing once <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> key, it quickly draws a thick border around the current window and then toggles to the previous window. When it's pressed for longer, it toggles VERY rapidly between all open windows.

This strange behaviour disables/consumes other key shortcut combinations which include the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> key i.e. <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> does not go back in previous page in a web browser.

When I log into Unity desktop, the key works just fine.

I've searched repeatedly for this issue online but without any luck.

*UPDATE*: I noticed that key combinations which start with <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> don't work at all, whereas those that are preceded by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) seem to not be affected by this issue.

*UPDATE 2:* I tried switching to a different display manager as suggested below (went from gdm3 to lightdm and back) but this did not solve my issue.

---

*UPDATE 3:* Following many months without any solution, a few days ago the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key stopped working completely (it is not even detected in the BIOS or in the terminal). Since this incident, the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> key is behaving as normal and the posted issue is, well, no more. So, I suspect it could have been all along a faulty <kbd>Esc</kbd> key causing all this mess.

Comment: That's strange! What you described can be achieved by the <Alt><Esc> combination, not sure why just <Alt> invokes the feature.

Comment: Yeah, I know! BTW, any ideas why my question was down-voted??! I thought I made clear what the issue is here.

Comment: @VitaminZ no idea why your question was downvoted people are quick on the downvote on this site.

Can you check if you can reproduce the behavior using <Alt><Esc> in unity? it may be that your esc key is stuck

Comment: Thanks @Fuseteam for your reply. Indeed <Alt><Esc> in Unity does nothing (it does not toggle between 2 windows). Otherwise, my <Esc> seems to be working just fine i.e. when I press it while editing a formula in Calc I exit the edit mode or when a system notification is displayed, I can dismiss it by pressing on <Esc>.

Comment: interesting but that confirms your left <Alt> somehow triggers <Esc>, if it's not stuck

Comment: @Fuseteam, thanks again, your comment pointed me to the right direction and I managed to answer my own question! :) I'll explain below in details.

Comment: @VitaminZ sure you're welcome, looking forward to your solution

Comment: @VitaminZ I don't know who downvoted your post or why they did that, but often it *feels* like some user(s) are engaging in serial downvoting. This was [raised on meta last month](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18826/480481).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following many months without any solution, a few days ago the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key started acting up: either it is stuck (as if it was pressed continuously) or it is not working at all (it is not even detected in the BIOS or in the console). In the later case, the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> key is behaving as normal and the posted issue is, well, no more. So, I suspect it could have been all along a faulty <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (apparently not a rare issue in Lenovo laptops) causing all this mess.

Comment: After replacing the keyboard, I can confirm that this issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Following on a comment by @Fuseteam, I went back and logged in Unity desktop to check out some things. I also went to the All Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts and started to verify each and every shortcut combination (something I'd already done numerous times but... in Gnome/Ubuntu desktop).

I noticed that in the "Launchers" group, next to "Key to show the HUD" there was this: <kbd>Left Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, *without* the plus sign "+" between the 2 keys (as is the norm in any other key combination)! So, I cleared/disabled the shortcut, exited, logged back in my normal Ubuntu desktop (Gnome) and the issue was no more!

So this combination (which I don't remember ever setting up myself and how could I ever enter it without the plus sign?!) was holding back the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> from functioning properly. Maybe it was the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 to blame which was not a clean install? Anyway, I hope this can help others having a similar issue/strange behaviour.

*UPDATE:* This worked only temporarily till my laptop resumed from suspend. Since then, the issue is back exactly as before.

Comment: ah so the HUD shortcut from unity was interfering with alt shortcuts in gnome........interesting

Comment: I can't believe this is happening (and I feel ill at ease to change the status of my own answer back to "unsolved"), but the issue came back after I suspended and returned to my notebook a few hours later... I did a full reset to all the shortcuts (again) to default to no avail. This time no weird shortcuts, neither in Unity nor in Ubuntu desktop. But something clearly captures the attention of my <Left Alt>...

Comment: Whelp that's weird. is it the same behavior or different?

Comment: Yest, it's exactly the same as before. Left <Alt> blocks all key shortcuts which start with it and whenever pressed (alone or in combination with other keys) just toggles between windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried (almost) everything. I am using Ubuntu MATE 18.04. The arrow keys stopped working after an update. Searched the web and tried everything that looked plausible. Finally I decided to change the window manager and that worked. MATE installs lightdm. I downloaded gdm3 and reconfigured to make gdm3 the default. I did this by ssh from another device as I was not sure how reconfigure would work inside the window manager.

```
sudo apt install gdm3
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service gdm3 start
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
sudo reboot.
```

To check, try:

```
sudo service --status-all | grep dm
```

Or:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

You should see that gdm3 is active.

After this, my MATE Terminal arrow keys were back to normal.

Comment: Hi @elaz and thanks for your answer. I run the two last commands and it seems that I'm already running the gdm3 as my display manager (which is the default in Ubuntu/Gnome 18.04). However, I switched to lightdm to see if the problem persists, which it does unfortunately. I even logged in Unity again and all was ok, as with the gdm3 under Unity. So switching to a different display manager does not solve my issue with <Alt>.